# MS Exchange to Mail

Tags: macos, apple-mail

Here is my issue: 
I have been trying for weeks now to get my professional email (exchange) onto my Mail app on my macbook.
I had no trouble doing it on my iPad . But it seems to be more difficult on the macbook .
I have the server address and I think every else which should be required but I am still failing.
Can someone please assist me.

Comment: error message? screenshot?

Answer (score 1):

Apple Support has a [topic](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3748) that explains how to do this in great detail.

```
1. Open Mail (click its icon in the Dock, or open it in the Applications folder).

2. From the Mail menu, choose Preferences.

3. Click Accounts in the toolbar.

4. Click the + icon. The "Add Account" sheet appears.
   Enter your real name, email address, and password;
   click Continue. If Autodiscovery is enabled you can
   skip to step 8.

   Note: If you do not know what to enter for any of these,
   contact your Exchange administrator.

   Note: If the Exchange server does not have Autodiscovery
   enabled, you will need to manually fill in your mail server
   information fields mentioned below (go to step 6).

5. The "Incoming Mail Server" sheet appears.

6. Select Exchange 2007 from the Account Type pop-up menu
   (the type of Exchange server you want to use is a
   Client Access Server (CAS) ), enter an optional description,
   enter the incoming mail server address, your user name, and
   password. 

   If you do not know what to enter for any of these, contact your
   Exchange administrator.

7. Select "Address Book contacts" and/or "iCal calendars" if you would
   like to automatically configure iCal and Address Book for use with 
   your Exchange server as well. 

8. Click Continue. The "Account Summary" sheet appears.

9. Review the information in the summary. If it appears to be correct, 
   click Create. If you need to make changes, click Go Back.

   Note: Select "Take account online" to take this account online immediately.
```